# windows 10 no me permite ejecutar aplicaciones como administrador?

Tags: windows, cuenta-usuario, administración-de-software

hola tengo una laptop lenovo con `windows 10` home y intento instalar java/etc y me pide ejecutarla como administrador y intento ejecutar el programa  pero no me permite decir "si" cuando me muestra la ventana para agregar usuarios.

Nota : **la computadora estaba bloqueada porque al anterior usuario se le olvido la contraseña**

y estoy intentando instalar java para posteriormente instalar `netbeans`

[este fue el tutorial que utilize para desbloquearla](https://es.wikihow.com/agregar-usuarios-desde-el-CMD)

este es el comando que use:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En inicio escribe simbolo del sistema y dale clik derecho -> ejecutar como administrador y ya tendras permiso para instalar desde consola

Answer (score 2, accepted):

la solucion que yo encontre para solucionar este problema es esta :

primero antes de iniciar sesion en windows 10 home entras al cmd en el login en este boton de accesibilidades de window 10 home y escribo el comando

**control userpasswords2** y despues selecciono donde dice que el equipo necesita usuario y contraseña para iniciar y selecciono al usuario actual y le doy en la opcion de propiedades y le doy previlegios de administrador, asi lo solucione cualquier duda comente.